# Can't use "pause" in function if "call" used with caret to split arguments

Tags: batch-file

I can't get this to work in a .bat file on windows 10. The console opens and exits skipping the pause in function.

```
@echo off

:: SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

echo.
call :test "param1",<nul ^
"param2",<nul ^
"param3",<nul ^
"param4"

exit

:test
cls

echo "%~1"
echo "%~2"
echo "%~3"
echo "%~4"

echo.
echo This pause doesn't work with caret to split parameters ↓
pause

exit /b
```

But this will work displaying the 2 pause

```
@echo off

:: SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

echo.
call :test "param1",<nul ^
"param2",<nul ^
"param3",<nul ^
"param4"

pause
exit

:test
cls

echo "%~1"
echo "%~2"
echo "%~3"
echo "%~4"

echo.
echo This pause doesn't work with caret to split parameters ↓
pause

exit /b
```

Any idea if it is even possible to make the first code to work keeping the carets to split arguments?

Yes the pause in function will work if I remove `<nul` but then I could not get the `param3` and `param4`. I'm in a dead end.

***Edit: The best solution is to avoid caret. Thanks for your enlightenments that confirm what I thought.***

Comment: Do you mean `^<nul ^`?

Comment: @jeb there is `pause` just before `exit` so the latter script shows the `Press any key to continue . . .` twice.

Answer (score 4):

```
call :test "param1",<nul ^
"param2",<nul ^
"param3",<nul ^
"param4"
```

is the same as

```
call :test "param1","param2","param3","param4" 0<nul
```

This means: *call* `:test` subroutine

- *supplying* four parameters `"param1","param2","param3","param4"`, and
- *reading **all keyboard input*** from file-like device `nul`.

Hence, all `pause` inside the `:test` subroutine is resumed immediately as it's *fed* from `nul`.

Read [Redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):

```
command < filename        Type a text file and pass the text to command
```

Numeric handles:

```
STDIN  = 0  Keyboard input
STDOUT = 1  Text output
STDERR = 2  Error text output
UNDEFINED = 3-9
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add `<nul ^` to the call, it has two different effects.

1) It suppresses the `pause` to wait, as the `pause` takes the input from `nul`
2) `<nul ^` changes the line continuation a bit, it avoids the escaping of the first character in the next line.

Btw. You don't need any commas to split arguments in the call.

You could simply use ( please note the first space in the lines)

```
call :test "param1" ^
 "param2" ^
 "param3" ^
 "param4"
```

If you really want to use the `redirect caret` behaviour, you can change the redirect from `<nul` to `2>nul`.
But then you *lose* the stderr output

```
call :test "param1" 2>nul ^
"param2" 2>nul ^
"param3" 2>nul ^
"param4"
```